# Выполнение запросов раз в пять секунд

Tags: postgresql

Пробовал через pg_cron, но он не позволяет выбрать интервал менее одной минуты. Сейчас смотрю в сторону pg_sleep, но проблема с синтаксисом. Скрипт имеет следующую структуру:

```
Прошу прощения! Так называемая петля есть. Корректный запрос:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_dat() RETURNS VOID AS $$
BEGIN
 INSERT INTO data (time, value)
 VALUES (NOW(), random()*10);
 SELECT pg_sleep(5);
 INSERT INTO data (time, value)
 VALUES (NOW(), random()*10);
 SELECT pg_sleep(5);
 INSERT INTO data (time, value)
 VALUES (NOW(), random()*10);
 SELECT pg_sleep(5);
 INSERT INTO data (time, value)
 VALUES (NOW(), random()*10);
 SELECT pg_sleep(5);
 INSERT INTO data (time, value)
 VALUES (NOW(), random()*10);
 SELECT pg_sleep(5);
 INSERT INTO data (time, value)
 VALUES (NOW(), random()*10);
 SELECT pg_sleep(5);
 INSERT INTO data (time, value)
 VALUES (NOW(), random()*10);
 SELECT pg_sleep(5);
 INSERT INTO data (time, value)
 VALUES (NOW(), random()*10);
 SELECT pg_sleep(5);
 INSERT INTO data (time, value)
 VALUES (NOW(), random()*10);
 SELECT pg_sleep(5);
 INSERT INTO data (time, value)
 VALUES (NOW(), random()*10);
 SELECT pg_sleep(5);
 INSERT INTO data (time, value)
 VALUES (NOW(), random()*10);
 SELECT pg_sleep(5);
 INSERT INTO data (time, value)
 VALUES (NOW(), random()*10);
 SELECT pg_sleep(5);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
-----------
Ошибка: 
ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function insert_dat() line 5 at SQL statement 

SQL state: 42601
```

При вызове данной процедуры получаю ошибку... В чём может быть проблема?

Суть задачи наполнять таблицу каждые 5 секунд... Планирую сделать таким образом петлю минутную, а после этого через pg_cron запускать каждую минуту.

Comment: А где текст ошибки? Он должен быть прямо в вопросе. Ну и наверное некий `loop` должен быть, а не прямо так вызов функции?

Comment: Прошу прощения, отредактировал пост. В нём корректный запрос + текст ошибки

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/companies/postgrespro/articles/335798/

Comment: pg_cron уже пробовал, менее 1 минуты нельзя выставить промежуток.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо

```sql
SELECT pg_sleep(5);
```

Напишите:

```sql
PERFORM pg_sleep(5);
```

Ошибка потому, что движок не понимает, зачем вы делаете `SELECT`, если не используете результат. Там в ошибке всё это прямо написано:

> ERROR:  query **has no destination for result data**

Ошибка: Не указано назначение для результирующих данных запроса.

> HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a `SELECT`, use **`PERFORM`** instead.

Подсказка: Если вы не хотите использовать результаты `SELECT`, используйте `PERFORM` вместо него.

Comment: Помогите еще с одним нюансом разобраться, скрипт отработал 1 минуту, как и задумывалось. Но в таблице значения времени без 5 секундного интервала...

Comment: Ссылка на селект с таблицы https://ibb.co/f8n4Zpx

Comment: @SabitHalimuzin Не смог ничего нагуглить на эту тему. Может он как-то кэширует результат работы `NOW()`... хотя это было бы очень странно.

Comment: Попробуйте написать процедуру, которая делает эти два действия, которые вы повторяете, и дёргать её также через `PERFORM`. Поменяется что-то или нет? Ну и вообще это бы в цикл всё завернуть попробовать.

Comment: Как вы думаете, будет ли смысл вмест NOW() попробовать CURRENT_TIMESTAMP?

Comment: Попробуйте )  Я пока не большой спец по постгресу, тут только пробовать.

Comment: Вот и я далеко не спец с постгресом:) Спасибо большое за помощь, буду рад, если чем-то смогу помочь в ответ. тг - @Sharipo_m